# Can I access the choice category in a Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's say I have this

```
    class PaymentType(models.Model):
        INSCRIPTION = 'INS'
        JANUARY = 'JAN'
        FEBRUARY = 'FEB'
        MARCH = 'MAR'
        APRIL = 'APR'
        MAY = 'MAY'
        JUNE = 'JUN'
        JULY = 'JUL'
        AUGUST = 'AUG'
        SEPTEMBER = 'SEP'
        OCTOBER = 'OCT'
        NOVEMBER = 'NOV'
        DECEMBER = 'DEC'

        NAME_CHOICES = [
            ('Months'), (
                (JANUARY, 'January'),
                (FEBRUARY, 'February'),
                (MARCH, 'March'),
                (APRIL, 'April'),
                (MAY, 'May'),
                (JUNE, 'June'),
                (JULY, 'July'),
                (AUGUST, 'August'),
                (SEPTEMBER, 'September'),
                (OCTOBER, 'October'),
                (NOVEMBER, 'November'),
                (DECEMBER, 'December')
            )
            ('Others'), (
                (INSCRIPTION, 'Inscription'),
            )
        ]
        amount = models.FloatField()
        payment_type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=NAME_CHOICES)
```

Is there a way that I can access the 'Months' or 'Others' category? For example I would like the user to be able to add more payment types to 'Others' or add/update the amount for all the 'Months'

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way that I can access the 'Months' or 'Others' category

I dont exactly understand this part, but I assume you want something as follows:

You can create another model and link it together via a DB foreign key, which is in Django represented with [ForeignKey column](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey). You can't use `choices` with `ForeignKey` the same way as with `CharField`, but in a form (I assume you'll have one) you can use [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) instead. Rough model prototype:

```
class PaymentMethod(models.Model):
    """model for your NAME_CHOICES."""
    id = models.CharField(max_length=8, primary_key=True) # `JAN` goes here
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32) # `January` goes here
    category = models.CharField(max_length=32) # `Months` goes here, but I'm not exactly sure about how this column will fit into the form


class PaymentType(models.Model):
    amount = models.FloatField()
    payment_type = models.ForeignKey(PaymentMethod)
```